# Bilinear property of dot-products

Tags: linear-algebra

I didn't understand the bilinear property of dot products. Is there a property of just being linear as well of some operation?

Comment: I think here it is pretty exhaustive, exactly, what don't you understand? Expand your question! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form

Comment: @Euler_Salter An operation that is linear but  not bilinear.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia it sounds like you're asking "why do we say that the dot-product is *bilinear* instead of saying that it's *linear*?".  Is that correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes. If possible please post an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

[Bilinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) is a property of functions that take as arguments two vectors. More specifically, a map $B : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is bilinear if $v \mapsto B(v,w)$ is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) for each $w \in V$, and $w \mapsto B(v,w)$ is linear for each $v \in V$.

It does not make sense (without further clarification) to ask if a function $B:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ of two arguments is linear, since linearity is defined for functions that take only one vector as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, no. The natural way to think of linearity for, say $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ is the preservation of scalar multiplication in both variables:

$$ f(\alpha x , \alpha y) = \alpha f (x,y) $$

along with the property of preserving vector addition.

However, if $f$ were bilinear, then:

$$ f(\alpha x , \alpha y) = \alpha^2 f(x,y) $$

That is, bilinear maps are **not** linear, if you define linearity in the way suggested above. (Though I do struggle to think of alternative definitions that aren't at least a little contrived.)